# System.Data.DataRowView in CombocBox C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a Windows forms application. I have two combo boxes, one to select the profile and the other to select the type of matrix. Each profile has a number of matrices which needs to be displayed in the combo box and set to the first matrix as default when the form loads.

I have set the data source and assigned the DisplayMember and Value member properties to both the combo boxes. However, when the form loads, in the second combo box where the different types of matrices should be listed, I have only System.Data.DataRowView for all the values. However, when I select the profile from the first comboBox, the second box is refreshed and the values are displayed correctly.

The code for the Profile comboBox

```
            ddProfile.DataSource = dtProfile;
            ddProfile.ValueMember = "ID";
            ddProfile.DisplayMember = "Description";
           
            ddProfile.Enabled = dtProfile.Rows.Count > 1;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dtProfile.Rows)
            {
                if (dr["Ordinal"].ToString() == "1")
                {
                    ddProfile.SelectedValue = dr["ID"];
                    break;
                }
            }

Code for the matrix comboBox
 
 DataTable dtMatrix = new DataTable();
            dtMatrix = DBConnector.GetTable("RiskMatrixList", "*", "", $"Profile={ddProfile.SelectedValue}", DBConnector.ConnectionType.Templates);
            dtMatrix = DBConnector.GetTable($"SELECT * FROM RiskMatrixList WHERE Profile={ddProfile.SelectedValue}");
            ddRiskMatrix.DataSource = dtMatrix;
            ddRiskMatrix.DisplayMember = "Description";
            ddRiskMatrix.ValueMember = "ID";
            
          
            ddRiskMatrix.Enabled = dtMatrix.Rows.Count > 1;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dtMatrix.Rows)
            {
                if (dr["IsDefault"].ToString() == "1")
                {
                    ddRiskMatrix.SelectedValue = dr["ID"].ToString();
                    break;
                }
            }      

Why am I not getting the right values when the form loads?
```

Comment: How the data is loaded in the combobox for the first time? Can you share that code?

Comment: Data is loaded using the datatables as the datasource. Data is fetched into the dataTable from the database, the code of which I have already included above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I observed that combo_SelectedValueChanged is called twice, when ValueMember and DisplayMember are being assigned, and then - I had the same problem.

After one day of very productive work :/ I discovered the trick:

1/ Added flag to form's properties:

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
    bool IsLoadingCombo = false;
```

2/ Simply modified combo_SelectedValueChanged:

```
private void cbFilter_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      if (isLoadingCombo)
          return;
     // rest of method's code
}
```

Not very elegant, but better than wasting the next few days.
I think, that problem is that "rest of method's code" needs selected value which is unknown, when the method is stupidly triggered when disp/value members are being asigned.

Comment: Found little bit better solution. Instead external flag isLoadingCombo - Enabled property could be used.  Before filling the combo set enabled=false. When datasource, valuemember and displaymember are assigned - then set enabled = true. SelectedValueChanged in then first line have to check for Enabled and immediately quit if sender is disabled.